# gnuplot - cannot typeset LaTeX title for a plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have this gnuplot script:

```
f(x) = 5 * log(x) / log(2) - 5 - sqrt(5 + x) 
F = '$5 \log_2(x) - 5 - \sqrt{5 + x}$'

set yrange [0:30]
set xrange [0:3000]

set terminal epslatex size 10.0cm,10.0cm color colortext
set output 'RunTimeComparisonTreeIndexed.tex'

set style line 1 linecolor rgb "#ff6666" linetype 1 linewidth 5

plot f(x) title F  with lines ls 1

replot
exit
```

I get an `.eps` file that looks like this:
[image: Unfunky eps]

So what I want to achieve, is typesetting the LaTeX expression in the gray legend box instead of a duplicate expression in Monospaced.

Comment: It works here. Which version of Gnuplot are you using?

Comment: @Thor gnuplot 4.6.7

Comment: @Thor I also tried 5.4.4, yet it produced the same result for me.

Comment: @Thor Could you show me your output via, say, Imgur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works here with the following script (only added standalone to `set terminal`):

*generate_tex.gp*

```
f(x) = 5 * log(x) / log(2) - 5 - sqrt(5 + x)
F = '$5 \log_2(x) - 5 - \sqrt{5 + x}$'

set yrange [0:30]
set xrange [0:3000]

set terminal epslatex standalone size 10.0cm,10.0cm color colortext
set output 'RunTimeComparisonTreeIndexed.tex'

set style line 1 linecolor rgb "#ff6666" linetype 1 linewidth 5

plot f(x) title F  with lines ls 1
```

Run:

```
gnuplot generate_tex.gp
pdflatex RunTimeComparisonTreeIndexed.tex
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks!